# Create toast notifications in FileObserver

Tags: android, toast

I'm using FileObserver to monitor a specific folder and upload new incoming files to my own server, parse the results and print out toast notification to the user of the result. The code snippet is as follows:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
data = readBytes(in);
if (data.length > 1){

    //Upload method here

    results = G.Upload(data);

    if(results.equals("PASS")){
        //Toast here
    }

    if(results.equals("FAIL")){
        //Different toast here
    }
}
```

Can I create a toast inside or do I need to pass the `results` variable to another class and print a toast notification from there? Many thanks.

**EDIT:** The above snippet is in the FileObserver class.

Comment: Is the code snipet above in the FileObserver class?

Comment: Yes it is in the FileObserver class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, try this

First lets make an interface called Observer

```
public interface ObserverActivity{
  public void onFileObserved(int Event, String path);
}
```

Next let's create our FileObserverSubclass

```
public class MyFileObserver extends FileObserver{
  private HashSet<ObserverActivity> registeredObservers;

public MyFileObserver(String path) {
    super(path, FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS);
    absolutePath = path;
    registeredObservers = new HashSet<ObserverActivity>();
}

public void registerObserver(ObserverActivity toRegister){
  registeredObservers.add(toRegister);
}

public void unregisterObserver(ObserverActivity toUnregister){
  registeredObservers.remove(toUnregister);
}

public void onEvent(int Event, String path){
  for(ObserverActivity o: registeredObervers){
    o.onFileObserved(Event, path);
  }
}
```

}

Finally, in the activity were we want to do toasts, we do this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ObserverActivity{
  MyFileObserver myFileObserver;
  protected onCreate(Bundle icicle){
    //other setup stuff
    myFileObserver = new MyFileObsever("path/to/monitor");
    myFileObserver.registerObserver(this);
    myFileObserver.startWatching();
  }


  protected onPause(){
    myFileObserver.stopWatching();
    myFileObserver.unregisterObserver(this);
  }

  protected onResume(){
    myFileObserver.registerObserver(this);
    myFileObserver.startWatching();
  }

  public void onFileObserved(int Event, String Path){
    //do toast in here.

  }
```

You have to do the stop and unregister because there's a chance we might never get back to this activity or it might be destroyed. If we never get back to it we're going to keep observing the file and using what ever resources that entails. That's wasteful and there for bad. We need to unregister because if the Activity is destroyed, the file observer would raise a null pointer exception when trying to call the onFileObserved method.

Note that according to the documentation for the startWatching function that:

> The monitored file or directory must exist at this time, or else no events will be reported (even if it appears later). If monitoring is already started, this call has no effect.

So make sure you've already started downloading your file.

Comment: So, this allows continuous monitoring of file/folder after one event has finished?